# Running a SSIS Package from SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I have set up a Import that copies data from a database on SQLExpress 2005 and Deletes and replaces the Data in a Database on SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

This Runs fine when i set it up for the first time? but if i try to assign a job in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to run the procedure at a set time it fails?

It also fails if i try to run the stored procedure manually? the only way i can get it too work is to re create from new each time?

Can anyone shed any light on why this may be happening?

The Error message i get ;

Date,Source,Severity,Step ID,Server,Job Name,Step Name,Notifications,Message,Duration,Sql Severity,Sql Message ID,Operator Emailed,Operator Net sent,Operator Paged,Retries Attempted
09/01/2014 15:51:14,PostingJob_Aron,Error,0,RFWSQL,PostingJob_Aron,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User sa.  The last step to run was step 1 (Import Data).,00:00:18,0,0,,,,0
09/01/2014 15:51:14,PostingJob_Aron,Error,1,RFWSQL,PostingJob_Aron,Import Data,,Executed as user: RFWSQL\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  15:51:15  Error: 2014-09-01 15:51:32.19     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: PostingImportAron Connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [1326]. ".  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:51:32.19     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - MyPostings [1]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:51:32.20     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Source - MyPostings" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:51:32.20     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:51:32.22     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task 1      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  15:51:15  Finished: 15:51:32  Elapsed:  17.14 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:18,0,0,,,,0
09/01/2014 15:45:59,PostingJob_Aron,Error,0,RFWSQL,PostingJob_Aron,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User sa.  The last step to run was step 1 (Import Data).,00:00:21,0,0,,,,0
09/01/2014 15:45:59,PostingJob_Aron,Error,1,RFWSQL,PostingJob_Aron,Import Data,,Executed as user: RFWSQL\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  15:45:59  Error: 2014-09-01 15:46:20.59     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: PostingImportAron Connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  ".  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:46:20.59     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - MyPostings [1]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:46:20.59     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Source - MyPostings" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:46:20.59     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:46:20.59     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task 1      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  15:45:59  Finished: 15:46:20  Elapsed:  21.14 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:21,0,0,,,,0
09/01/2014 15:24:00,PostingJob_Aron,Error,0,RFWSQL,PostingJob_Aron,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 24 (Run).  The last step to run was step 1 (Import Data).,00:00:22,0,0,,,,0
09/01/2014 15:24:00,PostingJob_Aron,Error,1,RFWSQL,PostingJob_Aron,Import Data,,Executed as user: RFWSQL\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  15:24:00  Error: 2014-09-01 15:24:21.93     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: PostingImportAron Connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  ".  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:24:21.93     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - MyPostings [1]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:24:21.93     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Source - MyPostings" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:24:21.93     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2014-09-01 15:24:21.93     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task 1      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  15:24:00  Finished: 15:24:21  Elapsed:  21.156 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:21,0,0,,,,0
09/01/2014 15:11:00,PostingJob_Aron,Error,0,RFWSQL,PostingJob_Aron,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 24 (Run).  The last step to run was step 1 (Import Data).,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0
09/01/2014 15:11:00,PostingJob_Aron,Error,1,RFWSQL,PostingJob_Aron,Import Data,,Executed as user: RFWSQL\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  15:11:00  Error: 2014-09-01 15:11:00.74     Code: 0xC0014060     Source: {7A71992F-6187-4E30-AB94-F6A949E6EC47}      Description: Failed to decrypt a package that is encrypted with a user key. You may not be the user who encrypted this package or you are not using the same machine that was used to save the package.  End Error  Could not load package "\PostingImportARON" because of error 0x8009000B.  Description: Key not valid for use in specified state.  Source:   Started:  15:11:00  Finished: 15:11:00  Elapsed:  0.125 seconds.  The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0

Comment: If you went to your physician and said, "I feel pain" are they going to be able to help you? No. Do you have a broken bone, a migraine, ruptured spleen, a splinter, upset stomach, lupus (it's never lupus) or any of a host of other ailments. Please update your question to specify what "it fails" means. Add the specific error messages, perhaps a screenshot of what your package looks like, relevant queries, etc

Comment: I have a text file with a lengthy error message but i cant see anyway of attaching it?

Comment: Open text file, select all, copy. Click Edit button above, paste

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the table names (destination) are hardcoded to be something.  So when run first time, it creates the object.

When you run a second time, that object already exists and therefore fails and exits out at that point in the code - ***not*** running your SP as it will be run as a single block or transaction.

What you need is something to check for the existence of the object name wrapped in an IF block so that the remaining logic can be processed.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourSpecificDates') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #YourSpecificDates
        /*Do other processes*/
        /*Exec your SP*/
    END
```

Comment: Hi that sounds like what may be happening, Where should i put the code and how should i run it? Will this be a Step before i run the Table copy?

Comment: You will need to edit your SSIS package and find the part that creates the destination table. Although seeing the error message you posted suggests that you also need to remove the encryption key, so that it can be executed